# Keras LSTM Sequence Classification - Loss and validation loss decreases by trival amount and accuracy and validation accuracy remains static

Tags: keras, classification, lstm, sequence, stock

Hoping for a quick second pair of eyes before I officially give up hope on applying deep learning to stock prediction.

The goal is to use an LSTM to predict one of two classes. The positive class corresponds to a sequence that led to a price increase of 5% or greater over the next six periods - the negative class corresponds to a sequence that did not.  As expected this has led to a bit of class imbalance with the ratio being about 6:1 negative to positive. **The problem right now though is that the model is showing the same accuracy across all epochs and is only predicting the negative class**. This makes me think that I may have a problem with the structure of my model. The input is adataframe which includes price data and few moving averages:

```
                   price_open  price_high  price_low  price_close       ma_8      ma_13      ma_21      ma_55  6prd_pctchange  entry_flag
time_period_start                                                                                                                        
11-02-2016 23:00     10.83280    10.98310   10.72591     10.96000  10.932415  10.855693  10.960608  11.087525        0.008535         0.0
11-03-2016 03:00     10.96016    11.02560   10.96000     11.00003  10.937569  10.873219  10.948081  11.075059        0.004544         0.0
11-03-2016 07:00     11.00007    11.14997   10.91000     11.00006  10.954170  10.919378  10.929689  11.062878       -0.007442         0.0
11-03-2016 11:00     11.05829    11.14820   10.90001     10.99208  10.959396  10.923376  10.912183  11.057317        0.008392         0.0
11-03-2016 15:00     10.90170    11.03112   10.70000     10.91529  10.938490  10.933783  10.890906  11.048504        0.006289         0.0
11-03-2016 19:00     10.89420    10.95000   10.82460     10.94980  10.944640  10.947429  10.882745  11.041227        0.005234         0.0
11-03-2016 23:00     10.94128    11.08475   10.88404     11.08475  10.974350  10.957118  10.888859  11.032288        0.011382         0.0
11-04-2016 03:00     11.02761    11.22778   10.94360     10.99813  10.987517  10.967185  10.893531  11.023518       -0.000173         0.0
11-04-2016 07:00     10.95076    11.01814   10.92000     10.92100  10.982642  10.964934  10.904055  11.011691       -0.007187         0.0
11-04-2016 11:00     10.94511    11.06298   10.89000     10.99557  10.982085  10.958244  10.914692  11.000365        0.000318         0.0
```

and has been converted into numpy arrays that are 6 periods in length and normalized using the scikit-learn method `MinMaxScaler`. As an example, the first sequence looks like below:

```
array([[0.        , 0.16552483, 0.09965385, 0.52742716, 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 1.        ],
       [0.5648144 , 0.37805671, 1.        , 0.9996461 , 0.19101228,
        0.19104958, 0.83911884, 0.73073358],
       [0.74180673, 1.        , 0.80769231, 1.        , 0.80630067,
        0.69421501, 0.60290376, 0.46764059],
       [1.        , 0.99114867, 0.76926923, 0.90586292, 1.        ,
        0.73780155, 0.37807623, 0.34751414],
       [0.30555679, 0.40566085, 0.        , 0.        , 0.22515636,
        0.85124563, 0.104818  , 0.15716305],
       [0.27229589, 0.        , 0.47923077, 0.40710157, 0.45309243,
        1.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])
```

When I build, compile, and fit a model on these sequences my results quickly plateau and the model ends up only predicting the negative class.

```
# Constants:
loss = 'binary_crossentropy'
optimizer = 'adam'
epochs = 12
batch_size = 300

# Complie model:
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy']) 
results = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), shuffle=False)
model.summary()
```

It outputs:

```
Epoch 1/12
22/22 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step - loss: 0.5696 - accuracy: 0.8410 - val_loss: 0.3953 - val_accuracy: 0.8885
Epoch 2/12
22/22 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4355 - accuracy: 0.8473 - val_loss: 0.3569 - val_accuracy: 0.8885
Epoch 3/12
22/22 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.4379 - accuracy: 0.8473 - val_loss: 0.3612 - val_accuracy: 0.8885
Epoch 4/12
22/22 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.4320 - accuracy: 0.8473 - val_loss: 0.3554 - val_accuracy: 0.8885
Epoch 5/12
22/22 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4338 - accuracy: 0.8473 - val_loss: 0.3577 - val_accuracy: 0.8885
Epoch 6/12
22/22 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4297 - accuracy: 0.8473 - val_loss: 0.3554 - val_accuracy: 0.8885
Epoch 7/12
22/22 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.4303 - accuracy: 0.8473 - val_loss: 0.3570 - val_accuracy: 0.8885
Epoch 8/12
22/22 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.4273 - accuracy: 0.8473 - val_loss: 0.3558 - val_accuracy: 0.8885
Epoch 9/12
22/22 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.4285 - accuracy: 0.8473 - val_loss: 0.3577 - val_accuracy: 0.8885
Epoch 10/12
22/22 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.4254 - accuracy: 0.8473 - val_loss: 0.3565 - val_accuracy: 0.8885
Epoch 11/12
22/22 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.4270 - accuracy: 0.8473 - val_loss: 0.3581 - val_accuracy: 0.8885
Epoch 12/12
22/22 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.4243 - accuracy: 0.8473 - val_loss: 0.3569 - val_accuracy: 0.8885
Model: "sequential_6"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_6 (LSTM)                (None, 100)               42400     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 101       
=================================================================
```

And a quick check shows that it is only predicting the negative class:

```
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
predictions_round = [1 if x > 0.5 else 0 for x in predictions]
pd.Series(predictions_round).value_counts()

0    1641
dtype: int64
```

**I'll be the first to say that this may be because predicting a stock price entry point is a task full of noise.** BUT I also expected the model to at least make a handful of wrong guesses instead of simply guessing all the same class. To me, that seems like an issue with the way I built the model or structured the inputs.

`X_train.shape` and `y_train.shape` give me `(6561, 6, 8)` and `(6561, )` respectively.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What’s the prevalence of “positive” cases in the training data? What you’re looking at may be a problem of “unbalanced classes”. 

That being said, stock prediction of that kind is indeed unlikely to make you rich. Any signal there might be is picked up much earlier more sophisticated models with far more computing power than you have, and observed stock prices are, almost by definition, the residual randomness.

Comment: One more thing: I’m. It sure how the sigmoid and ReLU activations interact here...sigmoid + rounding is 0 for anything < ≈ 10. Maybe try softmax?

Comment: @MatthiasWinkelmann I've responded in the original post. Appreciate the help.